# void function with return terminator

Tags: c, debugging, return, break, void

If I want to end the compiling of a void function, do I break or return NULL?

This is a piece of code that returns an error.

```
void addUser( const char *name ) {
    //create Usernode and void *data (user w/ friends)
    //check to see if User already exists
    if ( findUser(name) != NULL) {
        return;
    }
    //create data for node
    User *registeredData = malloc(sizeof(struct User_struct));  //first user Data

    registeredData->name = name;

    //create a Friends
        //put this in file create Friends

    Friends initAmigos;
    initAmigos = (Friends)malloc(sizeof(struct Friends_struct));        //NOTE: NO POINTERS HERE
    //set Friends list to Null
    initAmigos->amigos_Queue = que_create( NULL );
    registeredData->amigos = initAmigos;

    //void que_insert( QueueADT queue, void *data )
    que_insert( initAmigo , registeredData);
    printf("%s User was inerted \n", name);

}
```

Comment: malloc returns void*, take a look: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/

Comment: @duDE that wasn't the question AFAICT.

Comment: My guess was that there is a `typedef Friends_struct *Friends;` though the `//NOTE:` does make me think it may not be true.

Comment: The phrase "*return terminator*" is new to me ...

Comment: You cannot `return NULL;` from a `void` function. That would return a null pointer value, and you cannot return *any* value from a `void` function. Nor can you use `break`; that terminates the smallest enclosing loop or `switch` statement.

Comment: To end _compilation_, you can use `#error`...

Answer (score 2):

You can "return;" from a void function, which stops execution execution of the function, and returns to the calling code.

You said "stop compiling", which shows a misunderstand of the difference between execution and compiling.  Compiling+linking converts your code (in its entirety) into something that can be executed on a processor.  Functions are then "run" on that processor until they complete.  A `void` function can signal that its complete by having a `return` statement that has no value.

Comment: It might be worth adding explcitly that "running" the program is only possible after successful "compilation" of the program's sources followed by "linkage" of the result of compilation to the necessary libraries. Also the use of "*signaling*" is ambigious when talking C.

Comment: Thanks @alk, I've converted my answer into a community wiki, if you want to reword it. The question itself (given the example code) is fraught with misunderstandings.

Comment: Okay yes, to me ggcc -c is compile code. Executing a function I understand a subset of compiling.